# Dagger 2 multiple Repositories

Tags: dependency-injection, dagger-2, android-mvvm

So i am new to Dagger 2 dependency injection. I have created a custom ViewModelFactory class which returns my ViewModel.

```
@Singleton
public class CustomViewModelFactory implements ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    private final MyCatchesRepository repository;

    @Inject
    public CustomViewModelFactory(MyCatchesRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(MyCatchViewModel.class)) {
            return (T) new MyCatchViewModel(repository);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("ViewModel Not Found");
        }
    }
}
```

The `CustomViewModel` takes a `MyCatchesRepository` in the constructor and then creates the `MyCatchViewModel`.
How could i change this class so that i can use this ViewModelFactory to create different ViewModels with different constructor arguments (repositories)

This is the Module where the CustomViewModelFactory is created

```
@Module
public class RoomModule {

    private final MyDatabase myDatabase;

    public RoomModule(Application application) {
        this.myDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(application,
                            MyDatabase.class, AppConstants.DATABASE_NAME)
                            .build();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    MyCatchesRepository provideCatchesRepository(MyCatchDao myCatchDao) {
        return new MyCatchesRepository(myCatchDao);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    MyCatchDao providesCatchDao(MyDatabase myDatabase) {
        return myDatabase.myCatchDao();
    }


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    LuresRepository provideLureRepository(LureDao lureDao) {
        return new LuresRepository(lureDao);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    LureDao provideLureDao(MyDatabase myDatabase) {
        return myDatabase.lureDao();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    MyDatabase provideDatabase(Application application) {
        return myDatabase;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    ViewModelProvider.Factory provideCatchesViewModelFactory(MyCatchesRepository catchesRepository) {
        return new CustomViewModelFactory(catchesRepository);
    }
}
```

ViewModelModule

```
@Module
public abstract class ViewModelModule {

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(MyCatchViewModel.class)
    abstract ViewModel myCatchViewModel(MyCatchViewModel myCatchViewModel);

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(FishingSpotViewModel.class)
    abstract ViewModel fishingSpotViewModel(FishingSpotViewModel fishingSpotViewModel);

    @Binds
    abstract ViewModelProvider.Factory bindCustomViewModelFactory(CustomViewModelFactory customViewModelFactory);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach the Google team came up with in the architecture components samples is to use a custom annotation in order to provide ViewModel classes through dagger.

In Java the Annotation looks as follows.

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;
import dagger.MapKey;

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@MapKey
@interface ViewModelKey {
    Class<? extends ViewModel> value();
}
```

This uses MapKey from Dagger, where any annotated ViewModel will be composed into a Map which can then be used in your ViewModelFactory.

In the Google samples the ViewModelFactory looks as follows, where using constructor injection you can access the map of ViewModel providers.

```
public class ViewModelFactory implements ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    private final Map<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> viewModels;

    @Inject
    public ViewModelFactory(Map<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> viewModels) {
        this.viewModels = viewModels;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
        Provider<ViewModel> viewModelProvider = viewModels.get(modelClass);

        if (viewModelProvider == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("model class " + modelClass + " not found");
        }

        //noinspection unchecked
        return (T) viewModelProvider.get();
    }
}
```

In your example your would end up with the following in order to provide the MyCatchViewModel. Other ViewModels could then be provided by following the same pattern.

```
@Module
public abstract class ViewModelModule {
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(MyCatchViewModel.class)
    abstract ViewModel myCatchViewModel(MyCatchViewModel myCatchViewModel);
}
```

For a complete example you can check out the GithubBrowserSample sample from Google. https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/di/ViewModelModule.kt

Comment: I have gone through the code provided and the sample from Google. I only manage to get the MyCatchViewModel in the MyCatchFragment. When i try to get the FishingSpotViewModel it trows an exception `java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.applab.fishmemommvm.viewmodel.FishingSpotViewModel`

Comment: I am going to link the ViewModelModule class above

Comment: So MyCatchViewModel works? Do you have all your dependencies setup for FishingSpotViewModel? Do you also have an Inject setup on your ViewModel constructors, e.g. https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/b1a194c1ae267258cd002e2e1c102df7180be473/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/ui/search/SearchViewModel.java#L47

Comment: yea that what the problem. I missed an Inject setup on one of my ViewModels. Thank you very much for the help and guidance! :)